# View [] not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

The error log is:

> View [] not found. (View: 
>   /work/prj/resources/views/emails/notifyTest.blade.php)
>   {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): View [] not found.
>   (View: /work/prj/resources/views/emails/notifyTest.blade.php) at
>   /work/php/arousal-service-common/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137,
>   InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): View [] not found. at
>   /work/php/arousal-service-common/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137)

I try to send an email like this:

```
$mail = new \App\Email\NotifyEmail(
                'Title',
                'content');
            $mail->onQueue('email');
            \Mail::to($email)->queue($mail);

$mail = new \App\Email\NotifyEmail(
                'name',
                'gender');
            $mail->onQueue('email');
            \Mail::to($email)->queue($mail);


public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject("this is test notification email")
            ->markdown(
                'emails.notifyTest',
                [
                    'name'   => $this->name,
                    'gender' => $this->currency,
                ]
            );
    }
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Your Program can't find that View means blade page

Comment: Actually, the blade page does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Clear your config: `php artisan config:clear`
2. Restart your queue: `php artisan queue:restart`
3. Make sure that your blade/markdown file is valid.

I have had this problem before and realized that my markup file was invalid. I didn't have a closing `@endcomponent`

Answer (score 0):

First you should check blade file

```
views/emails/notifyTest.blade.php
```

if has then fire bellow commands

```
php artisan optimize --force
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
```